# Recuperar ultimo ID inserido DataSnap / SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Estou utilizando SqlServer com minha aplicação Delphi XE10 DataSnap, porém quando faço uma inserção gostaria que o servidor me retornasse o id que acabou de ser inserido no campo autoincremento (identity) do sqlserver para que eu pudesse mostrar ou atualizar a tela do cliente.

Comment: Sua dificuldade é obter o valor de retorno do campo *identity* ou fazer a função DataSnap retornar seu valor?

Answer (score 0):

Ailton eu utilizo bastante essas duas opções que os sql server nos dá:

IDENT_CURRENT retorna o último valor de identidade gerado para uma tabela específica em qualquer sessão e escopo.
Mas é preciso garantir que seu insert funcionou, se não ele vai pegar a última Identity da tabela mesmo sem inserir nada.

Ex: 
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('NOME_TABELA')

GO

SCOPE_IDENTITY retorna o último valor de Identity gerado para qualquer tabela na sessão e no escopo atuais.
Esta é claro que você também deve garantir o INSERT funcionou, a diferença é que ao invés de olhar diretamente a tabela ele olha a sessão atual que ele foi executado, ou seja, ele apenas irá pegar o Identity gerado naquela sessão.

Ex:
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

GO

O resultado de ambas opções você pode armazenar em uma variável e manipular do jeito que quiser.

Answer (score -1):

Na função que você passa os dados do cliente para o servidor inserir no banco, coloque "out variavel" o out devolve para você o retorno de um dado.